# Format array outputs in form serialize PHP

Tags: php

Im currently using the json_encode in converting array to strings 
which outputs data in a straight pattern in my table

```
user
-----------
id | name
-------------------------------------------
1  |"name1","name2","name3","name4","name5"
```

But i want to have an output where the table data will look like this.

```
user
-----------
id | name
-----------
1  | name1
2  | name2
3  | name3
4  | name4
5  | name5
```

My PHP code

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "dbsample");

if(isset($_POST["check_val"])){

$check_val = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags("check_val"));
$number = json_encode($_POST["name"]);

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($number); $i++) {
        if ($number[$i] != "") {

                $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_name(name) VALUES (?)";
                $stmt = $connect->prepare($query);
                $number[$i] = htmlspecialchars(strip_tags($number[$i]));
                $stmt->bind_param("s", $number);
                if($stmt->execute()) {  

                    echo "SUCCESS";
                    # code...
                }else
                {
                    echo "ERROR";

                }
        }
        else{

            echo "Please Enter Name";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Just replace `$number = json_encode($_POST["name"]);` with `$number = $_POST['name'];` and replace `$stmt->bind_param("s", $number);` with `$stmt->bind_param("s", $number[$i]);`

Comment: What's that check_val stuff all about?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer thanks! well that was easy :P